# keypress fail to work on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client event works fine on desktop browser but fail to do the same on mobile browser "Chrome".

It detects the key entry of "g" after "@" and replace it with "@gmail.com".
Any idea how to get it to work on mobile phone as well? thx

```js
Template.input.events({
  'keypress input': function (evt, template) {
    if (evt.which === 13) {
      //do stuff
    }
    else if (Session.get('taskSelected') === 'walk') {
      if (evt.which == 103) { // "g" has been typed do gmail.com
        utility.inputReplaceWith('gmail.com', evt);
      }
      else if (evt.which === 121) {  // "y" for yahoo.com
        utility.inputReplaceWith('yahoo.com', evt);
      }
      else if (evt.which === 104) {
        utility.inputReplaceWith('hotmail.com', evt);
      }
    }
  }
});

    inputReplaceWith: (text, evt) => {
      let elem = document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;
      if (elem.slice(-1) == '@') { // last char is "@"
        evt.preventDefault();
        document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value = elem + text;
      }
    },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture keys typed on android virtual keyboard using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `"keypress"` event in Chrome for Android is troublesome.

See:

- [keycode is always zero in Chrome for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139039/keycode-is-always-zero-in-chrome-for-android)
- [Capture keys typed on android virtual keyboard using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript)

TL;DR: use `"keydown"` and/or `"keyup"` event(s) instead, or even `"input"` event.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `textInput` event that gives you the entered character and is also cancellable

```
const inputField = document.getElementById('wanted-input-field');

inputField.addEventListener('textInput', function(e) {
    // e.data will be the 1:1 input you done
    const char = e.data; // In our example = "a"

    // If you want the keyCode..
    const keyCode = char.charCodeAt(0); // a = 97

    // Stop processing if "a" is pressed
    if (keyCode === 97) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46673783/5292302) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)