# keyup, keydown and keypress events not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get this to work but I don't know what's going on, the code I have:

```
$('#buscar-producto').on('keydown', function(e){
    console.log('hello');
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

It works on computers, but not on mobile..

**EDIT:**
I need to get the keyCode when a key is pressed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139039/keycode-is-always-zero-in-chrome-for-android

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan No, for this problem I'm not even getting an output, as if the event is not attached to the input...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`keydown` *should* work, but you could use the `input` event which seems to have undesired effects on Android mobile...
To get the *code* of the pressed key use the jQuery's normalized `Event.which`

**Android Chrome** tested:

#### Using `input` Event (`e.which` gives always `0` so it seems like a bug on android devices)

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

  $('#buscar-producto').on('input', function(e){
    var key = e.which || this.value.substr(-1).charCodeAt(0);
    alert( key )
  });

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="buscar-producto" placeholder="Buscar...">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

#### Using `keydown` (works as expected)

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

  $('#buscar-producto').on('keydown', function(e){
    alert( e.which );
  });

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="buscar-producto" placeholder="Buscar...">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: I missed something in my question, could you re-read it please? :)

Comment: Use `input` as Roko mentioned and use `event.which` to get the keycode. See more at : https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: keydown is now broken. Running this page on mobile with Desktop Mode so that snippet is available always gives 229 no matter what is pressed. On desktop, the correct character code comes up. Does anyone know what is causing this or what the fix is?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `event.key`, `event.keyCode`, `event.which`.

If above all not working then you can try `event.target.value.splice(-1)`

Comment: For me `splice` broke, I had to do `slice(-1)` instead