# Jquery on input from touchscreen find current input

Tags: jquery, input

I have user keypress and keydown to get the current key pressed, but it won't work on touchscreen.

I figured that I need to use `.on('input')` but how do I get that input?

In other words. I need this to work on a touchscreen:

```
$('#newtags').keypress(function(e){ 
  if (e.which==13 || e.which==32 || e.which==188){ 
    Do something
  }
});
```

UPDATE:
Thank you for you input. I have used the method where i check the input-fields last character, and remove the last character when function runs:

```
$('#newtags').on('keyup', function(e){
  var valueofinput= $(this).val();
  var lastcharofinput = valueofinput.substr(valueofinput.length - 1);

  if (e.which==13 || e.which==32 || e.which==188 || e.which==190 || lastcharofinput==' ' || lastcharofinput==',' || lastcharofinput=='.'){
    if (lastcharofinput==' ' || lastcharofinput==',' || lastcharofinput=='.'){
      valueofinput = valueofinput.substr(0, valueofinput.length - 1);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide code sample to help others understand your problem?

Comment: $('#newtags').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which==13 || e.which==32 || e.which==188){

Comment: You can also look at the Value and review the last character, and look for `" "` or `"-"` instead. Touchscreen devices use a virtual keyboard, so some of the same events don't trigger. You might consider one of the Mobile frameworks that can help capture those events in the same way a desktop browser does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to your question, the following can be reviewed: [keyup, keydown and keypress events not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478453/keyup-keydown-and-keypress-events-not-working-on-mobile)

```
$('#newtags').on('keydown', function(e){ 
  switch(e.which){
    case 13:
      console.log("Enter Pressed.");
      break;
    case 32:
      console.log("Space Pressed.");
      break;
    case 188:
      console.log("Dash Pressed.");
      break;
  }
});
```

You can use `if()` as well, `switch()` can be helpful for multiple scenarios.