# jquery keydown not work for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code.

```
$(".input_text").keydown(function (e) {
   let char = e.key;
   if(char == "A"){
      //my code
   }
});
```

This code works perfect for computers, but when I test it with **my mobile phone** it's not working. When I alert char I got 'undefined'. I tried many solutions form net but unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Did you try e.which? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478453/keyup-keydown-and-keypress-events-not-working-on-mobile

Comment: Thanks but for my requirement I can't use key codes :'(

Comment: More here. Also try the lower case "a" instead of the capital letter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed#302161