# contenteditable onkeydown does not work on andriod/mobile

Tags: html, jquery, contenteditable, onkeydown

I'm trying to use `contenteditable` with an `onkeydown` event which should limit my characters input. However I've stumbled across an issue on mobile where this `onkeydown` event is not working properly, but it works on desktop.

Can anyone help me with this? I just want a method to limit the characters input in the `contenteditable` that works on desktop & mobile. At the moment it only works for on desktop.

```html
<div onkeydown="return (this.innerText.length <= 11)" contenteditable="true" onpaste="return false;" placeholder="RUN A AWAY" id="quote__text" class="editable"></div>
```

If i had to use input, how can i make it expand as the text grows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keyup, keydown and keypress events not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478453/keyup-keydown-and-keypress-events-not-working-on-mobile)