# Disable spaces on input not working for devices

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to disable spaces on keydown, is working fine on desktop browsers but not working on devices like android.

In Javascript I use next script:

```
function noSpaces(e) {
    return e.which === 32 ? false : true;
}
```

And on HTML I use:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="return noSpaces(event)" />
```

Any idea why is not working on devices?

Comment: `? false : true` this is unneeded. Try `return e.which !== 32;` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does returning false in the keydown callback does not stop the button click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639338/why-does-returning-false-in-the-keydown-callback-does-not-stop-the-button-click)

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for the simplification, but anyway is not working on devices.

Comment: Likely to help | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139039/keycode-is-always-zero-in-chrome-for-android

Comment: Are you going to type on the keyboard on an Android device?

Comment: @mordad I already try that, and is not working on devices.

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini yes, I mean, I know is not physical keyboard, is any different script to do it?

Comment: No, it's not possible as you think and maybe it is but I don't have any idea how. Maybe there is another library for it in JS? search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual keyboard on mobile devices may give an unexpected value for Event.which, in many cases it will return value 229 (reference [caniuse keyboardevent-which](https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-which)).
Event.which is also deprecated. So what you should do is to use the more standard `Event.key`. Note that Event.key isn't based on code-number (like 32, 33, 34,...), you must use correct value (see more at [MDN KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)).
So your example should be corrected into something like this: `e.key === " "`

Comment: I try this, still working on desktop, but not on device.

Comment: I try it in different device browser and is working fine, so I suppose that is Samsung Browser issue. Thanks