# keyPress event not firing in Android mobile

Tags: javascript, android, backbone.js, marionette

I am using `backbone,marionette` for my Application.I used same code for both `desktop and mobile` but `keypress` not working in `mobile`.I made a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Snz/3/) for testing.

If you open this link in `mobile` event not firing,If you open in `desktop` it's firing.How can I resolve this.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the Android version? >=4.4?

Comment: @aravind I am using `motorola moto g` with version `4.4.2`

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302986/no-keypress-events-for-certain-keys-in-android-browser. The issue with  android >=4.4, the browser doesn't fire `keypress` events all the time. Use `input` event, it is reliable.

Comment: @aravind I tried your idea,but `keycode` not working.can you check the  `http://jsfiddle.net/33Snz/14/`.getting `undefined`

Comment: Ah, my bad. Got your problem, you are trying to prevent default in case it is not a number. Your solution is correct http://stackoverflow.com/a/22499179/1304559 for that issue. But keypress event not firing is not resolved I guess :(

Comment: @aravind I am facing one more problem,can you this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503559/backspace-not-firing-the-keyup-event-in-android-mobile`.

Answer (score 12):

Chrome mobile doesn't support keypress events properly for now. There is a long standing bug for this:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639

<s>I believe it should be fixed in v38.</s> The bug report was closed as "won't fix".

Comment: strangely, you DO get proper key codes if you hold down the ALT key (I'm using Hacker's Keyboard), although this is extremely annoying and really slows down typing.

Answer (score 7):

I will suggest two events on input box.

**This will work on desktop webbrowser.**

1) `onkeypress = return isNumberKey(event);`

```
function isNumberKey(e)
{
    var evt = e || window.event;

    if(evt) 
    { 
        var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        return true; 
    }

    if((charCode > 47 &&  charCode < 58) || charCode == 9 || charCode == 8 || charCode ==46 || charCode ==37 || charCode==39)
    { 
        return true; 
    }

    return false;
}
```

**This will work for mobile**

2) `onkeyup="numberMobile(event);"`

```
function numberMobile(e){
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
    return false;
}
```

Apply both event on the input box and it will work.Only drawback is,It make it slow.But for now we have to live with it.

There is one issue woth this solution.Left navigation is not working.I will update more appropriate solution soon.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like `keypress` event has been deprecated (Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) and it is better to use `keydown` event now before all browser drop support on it.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found a problem,but it won't work in opera.Instead of writing the code for numeric fields.I just added an attribute type='number' to input field in html file.Now only numeric keypad is coming.So it satisfies my requirements.Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Snz/11/)

html code:

```
<input type='number'/>
```

Comment: So have you found a solution to your problem? Can you share it?

Comment: Open the `jsFiddle`,it was mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I opened the one here http://jsfiddle.net/33Snz/11/. Looks like the event is commented out `//"beforeinput #search_input":"typeOfField"`. Please correct me if I am missing something

Comment: @aravind If you mention `type='number'`,you don't need to write any extra code.that's why I hided.

Comment: Ok, I get it.. So you have avoided the problem of handling `keypress` events. Thanks for explaining. Updating your question would help, because it sounds misleading.

Comment: @aravind check my previous comment(I added below my question.)

Answer (score 3):

With my experience i would like to share my knowledge,

**Desktop Browsers**

```
<input type="number">
```

1. Safari - allows Chars too (may be depends on version)
2. maxlength not supported.
3. Cursor position is unable to detect.
4. @keypress event detected.

---

```
<input type="text">
```

1. works as expected.

---

```
<input type="tel">
```

1. works as expected.

---

**Android Mobile Browser (Chrome)**

```
<input type="number">
```

1. Opens numeric keypad
2. @keypress event detected.
3. Cursor position is unable to detect.

---

```
 <input type="text">
```

1. @keypress event not even detected.
2. maxlength not working properly.

---

```
 <input type="tel">
```

1. @keypress event is detected.
2. maxlength supported.
3. Cursor position in input field can be detected.

---

**Note:**
For detecting cursor position I used,

```
let caretPos = e.target.selectionStart
```

Let me know is there are any ways to detect cursor position in **input[type="number"]**.

---

**Suggestion**

For Desktop browsers, use **input[type="text"]** to handle cases like keypress event and replace some values using cursor position.

For Android browsers, use **input[type="tel"]** to handle same cases mentioned above.