# The keypress in mobile not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a code which works really well in desktop, but not in mobile, i need to solve it. Here is my javascript code:

```
function O000OOO(e) {
var O0000O0;
if (window.event) {
    if (window.event.type == "keypress") {
        O00OO00 = -1
    }
    if (window.event.type == "keypress") {
        O00OO00 = window.event.keyCode
    }
    if (parseInt(O00OO00) > 0) {
        O0000O0 = O00OO00
    } else {
        O0000O0 = window.event.keyCode
    }
} else {
    if (e.type == "keypress") {
        O00O0OO = e.which;
        O00OO00 = -1
    }
    if (e.type == "keypress") {
        O00OO00 = e.which
    }
    if (parseInt(O00OO00) > 0) {
        O0000O0 = O00OO00
    } else {
        if ((parseInt(O00O0OO) > 0) && (e.which < 1)) {
            O0000O0 = O00O0OO
        } else {
            O0000O0 = e.which
        }
    }
}
return (parseInt(O0000O0))
```

}

Can anyone tell me, how to make it work in mobile too. When i type in my pc it works, but not in phone, why? How can i fix it?

Comment: maybe it does not like 0s and Os [sarcasm]

Comment: How is `O000OOO`'s event bound?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473950/keypress-event-not-firing-in-android-mobile

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged this with jquery-mobile, so it looks as if you can use jQuery. In that case, you can use `keyup` instead of keypress, which preferable. It reduces the chance that the input can be repeated if the key is held too long.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `input` instead of `keypress`.