# jQuery keypress event not working on mobile device

Tags: android, jquery

I'm trying to restrict a field to input specific values like only floats, i'm using keypress event to handle it. It is working fine on desktop browser but not working on mobile devices. I'm using android

```
    $(function() {
    $(document.body).on('keypress', '.number-only', function (evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        var value = $(this).val();
        var dotcontains = value.indexOf(".") != -1;
        if (dotcontains){
            if (charCode == 46) return false;
        }
        if (charCode == 46){
            return true;
        }
        if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried the `keyup` event instead?

Comment: yes, but not working as well

Comment: If you are using chrome browser on mobile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473950/keypress-event-not-firing-in-android-mobilehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473950/keypress-event-not-firing-in-android-mobile

Comment: yes i'm using chrome

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25826882/6588498

Comment: Keyboard events work differently in different devices.   please go through the link https://www.outsystems.com/blog/javascript-events-unmasked-how-to-create-input-mask-for-mobile.html

Comment: @CryptexTechnologies this solution works fine, but we can't enter floating values.